# Configuring navigation drawer doesn't show anything but the background

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer. I followed some tutorials and tweak some of the codes to satisfy my app needs. Now the problem is, the list of items that I want to display is not displaying. Basically I'm just creating an adapter that should be the one holding the content of my list.

Here are the codes:

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

 <!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item >Dashboard</item>
    <item >Flashcard</item>
    <item >Qbank</item>
    <item >Video Assist</item>
    <item >Contact Us</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Nav Drawer List Item Icons -->
<!-- Keep them in order as the titles are in -->
<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ico_dashboard_squared</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_flashback</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_qbank</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_contact_us</item>
    <item>@drawable/ico_contact_us</item>
</array>
```

NavigationDrawListAdapter

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private String[] data;
private TypedArray data2;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, String[] data1, TypedArray data2){
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data1;
    this.data2 = data2;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(data2.getInt(position, 0));        
        txtTitle.setText(data[position]);

        return convertView;
}
```

}

My configuration of the drawer:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerListLeft = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_slidermenu);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;

    mDrawerListLeft.getLayoutParams().width = width - 150;
    mDrawerListLeft.setLayoutParams(mDrawerListLeft.getLayoutParams());

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);
    mDrawerListLeft.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's a screenshot of the screen

[image]

I don't actually know why the list is not there but the background I supplied is there. As you can notice, I don't have an action bar because I don't really need one. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: where do you have the configuration drawer code? Inside onCreate?

Comment: yes ofcourse, it's inside this method configureDrawers(), and I'm calling this onCreate()

Comment: try to remove these two lines: mDrawerListLeft.getLayoutParams().width = width - 150;
    mDrawerListLeft.setLayoutParams(mDrawerListLeft.getLayoutParams());

Comment: actually that's an additional code i tried. before even including those codes, there are still no display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the adapter. Try to modify it:

```
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return data1.length;
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return data1[position];
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't notice this part. Really appreciate this.